# What to do with these errors when I open a PSD file in my Photoshop CS3 (Windows 7) while PSD is made by Photoshop (Mac OSX)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, mac, windows

I'm a Web Designer and when I open some PSD files in my Photoshop CS3 (Windows 7) I get these messages pop-up before to open PSD. My fellow designer use Photoshop on Mac OSX.

**Error 1**

> Some text layers contain fonts that are missing. These layers will
>   need to have the missing fonts replaced before they can be used for
>   vector based output.

[image]

**Error 2**

> Some groups were found corrupted and repaired.

[image]

**Error 3**

> This document contains unknown data which will be discarded to keep
>   layers editable. To preserve the origional appearance instead, choose
>   Flatten to load composite data as a flattened image.

[image]

Comment: Start by making sure you and your designers are using the same font files on your systems.

Comment: No I don't have many font's which designer have. But is it necessary to have same fonts? I don't need to edit the text most of the time. I just hide the text and save background as a image and write text in html.

Comment: oh, if you're not using any of the type set in PSD as images, then no, you don't need to worry about the fonts (you'll just have to live up with the pop-up warnings)

Comment: In answer I want to know the reason and suggested solution for each error message in detail

Comment: The first error is Font related. I believe the other two are well, though not positive. I usually flatten the image when I see the last prompt when working with other designer's PSD files. I then save that out as a JPG and then re-open the original PSD in layers. I use the JPG as my guide to see what might be different in the layered version minus the fonts I don't have. I then then pick out the image elements In need in the PSD to create the appropriate HTML and CSS and check it against the flattened JPG.

Answer (score 7):

**Error 1** This particular message is not significant. It just means that the font file you have is not the same version as your colleague's, and there's no harm in telling PS to update the layers. A "Missing Font" error is more important; it means he used a font you don't have. That would be handled by having the designer either rasterize or outline (convert to shape) all font layers before sending the file to you. Since you don't need to edit the text, it doesn't matter whether it's actual text or just a shape.

**Error 2** probably means exactly what it says, and is for information only. Photoshop has already repaired the problem.

**Error 3** tells you that your designer has a more advanced version of Photoshop (a later version and/or Photoshop Extended) and has included features that your version doesn't recognize. Smart Filters or 3D layers would be examples of this. A few minutes of dialog between you would probably identify these quite quickly. If you upgrade to CS5.1 or CS5.1 Extended you won't see this one again.

Comment: Regarding #3, I have CS5 extended. But still getting the error on most files. Is CS5 and 5.1 very different andnot compatible with CS6+?

Comment: There are features in CS6 that don't exist in CS5. See http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/whats-new-cs6.html for the complete list. Blur gallery as smart filters, for example, would not be understood by CS5, nor would the photographic blurs themselves. The oil paint filter wouldn't be recognized unless you had the Pixel Bender plug-in installed. And one of the major changes was true vector layers, replacing the old shape layers.

Answer (score 1):

Error 1 means your fellow designer used fonts that you don't have installed in your computer. If you don't need the texts, ignore this one.

Error 2 and 3 mean that you are using an older version of Photoshop, and some of the more advanced features are not recognized by your version. I would suggest asking your colleague what would he/she be using that is not supported on your version, or compare a flattened version (by your colleague) to the PSD file opened in your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Layout of a web page includes all of the font information - kerning, size, leading, etc. Since larger or smaller characters will cause text to be pushed around a text area / div / etc. you'll need the same fonts if you want to view the layout the same way the other designer does.

Unless you're strictly editing copy (which you could do much more efficiently with an HTML editor) you will, in fact, need the same fonts as the other designer.

OR...

you could pin the other designer down to a specific set of fonts or font family. If you don't have a font it's entirely possible that one of your viewers won't, either. Unless you're going to display all of your copy as rasterized images (which makes it impossible for crawlers to find keywords) you should probably make sure you're not trying to do layout with overly esoteric fonts.

Answer (score 0):

**Error 1:** You need the fonts used in the document. If you haven't, photoshop will show them as they seems. But you can no longer edit/convert to shape them.

**Error 2:** Photoshop does what's required. You don't need to do anything.

**Error 3:** Some image editing programs using a different layering method than photoshop. Photoshop can't recognize them and for a solution, it flattens the image to avoid any corruption.